# Optimized update

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I have been trying a massive update on a huge table (around 6 millions rows) with 2 columns (id and nb_send)

I need only to increment one column (nb_send)

This is the query:

```
UPDATE nb_send 
  SET n_nb_send = n_nb_send + 1 
WHERE n_id = ( .., .., .. with the 100K ids, etc.. )
```

And when I want to update 100K rows it takes a lot of time (I've never waited till the end because it exceeds the 40 mins) And I want to do it in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: You could perhaps provide some hints as to what is taking the time? Are you saturating disk I/O? Do you have a log of foreign keys? Does it just take a long time to locate these 100K rows? Only you have access to your particular machine and unless you share some details then nobody can say much that is terribly useful.

Comment: Do the update in smaller transactions? (Try for example 1 - 10k rows / transaction)

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: 40 minutes for updating 100k records? Sounds like some record is locked by another process. Check pg_stat_activity for waiting activity.

Comment: This is the config of my table (under Postgresql 9.1.14) : 
n_id_mail character varying(16) NOT NULL
n_nb_envoi smallint NOT NULL and there are no indexes.

Comment: For exemple, when I try an update on 100 rows it is working but when I've tried the same update on 2000 rows it is not working.

Comment: "it is not working" is rarely a useful description of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this case, is instead of creating a column (as a counter) and updating it, create a new table which count what you wants with all the information you need.

"WHERE id = " is not at all optimized for huge tables.

Comment: `WHERE id = (.., ..,)` is invalid SQL to begin with. If at all you would need to use `WHERE id IN (..., ...)`

Comment: I mean IN instead of =

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all indexes from this table (and indexes from tables using nb_send column), then update nb_send and then recreate all indexes.

I hope this will help